# How do I change the program memory through config.bib in Wince 6.0?

Tags: memory, windows-ce, platform-builder, windows-embedded

I get an error:
PROGRAM MEMORY IS LOW
Convert some Storage Memory to Program Memory... Use System
Control panel to adjust memory later.

I would like to change the program memory through config.bib.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FSRAMPERCENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee479036%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx)